# Дано натуральное число N. Найти все натуральные числа меньшие N, которые являются палиндромами. C++

Tags: c++

Дано натуральное число N. Найти все натуральные числа меньшие N, которые являются палиндромами. Не знаю, как решить.

Comment: Что именно у вас вызывает затруднение?

Comment: сама задача, не знаю, как реализовать ее решение

Comment: А что будет, если в строку поиска ввести `число палиндром` ?

Comment: "реализовать"? Значит, сама идея решения у вас есть?

Comment: все, сам разобрался

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>


using namespace std;

int palindrome(int N)
{
    int n = 0;
    while (N)
    {
        n = 10 * n + N % 10;
        N /= 10;
    }

    return n;
}

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");

    int N;
    cout << "Введите число N: ";
    cin >> N;

    for (int i = N; i > 10; i--)
    {
        if (i == palindrome(i))
        {
            cout << i << " ";
        }
    }
    _getch();
}
```

Comment: это слишком долго...   Можно придумать алгоритм не проверяющий каждое число.  Но  лучше просто  брать все палиндромы, меньшие данного числа, начиная от двузначных чисел,